# How to render sigma.js graph in python Dash html.Div?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash, sigma.js

I would like to build a Python Dash app with a sigma.js graph and am therefore trying to make it run with a bare minimal example. My folder structure looks as follows:

```
    DashGraph/
├── app3.py
└── assets
    └── sigma.min.js
```

And my code like this:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True, assets_folder='assets')

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H2("Sigma.js Graph"),
        html.Div(
            id="graph-container",
            children=[
                html.Div(id="sigma-container", style={"width": "100%", "height": "500px", "border": "1px solid #ccc"}),
            ],
        ),
        html.Button("Load Graph", id="load-graph-button"),
        dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
        html.Div(id='page-content')
    ]
)

init_sigma_script = """
function initSigmaGraph() {
    if (typeof sigma === 'undefined') {
        console.error('Sigma.js is not loaded');
        return;
    }

    // Initialize sigma.js with example data
    var s = new sigma({
        graph: {
            nodes: [
                { id: 'n0', label: 'Node 0', x: 0, y: 0, size: 3 },
                { id: 'n1', label: 'Node 1', x: 1, y: 1, size: 3 },
                { id: 'n2', label: 'Node 2', x: 2, y: 2, size: 3 },
            ],
            edges: [
                { id: 'e0', source: 'n0', target: 'n1' },
                { id: 'e1', source: 'n1', target: 'n2' },
                { id: 'e2', source: 'n2', target: 'n0' },
            ]
        },
        container: 'sigma-container',
        settings: {
            defaultNodeColor: '#ec5148'
        }
    });

    // Add interactivity
    s.bind('clickNode', function(e) {
        alert('Node clicked: ' + e.data.node.label);
    });
}
"""

@app.callback(
    Output("graph-container", "children"),
    [Input("load-graph-button", "n_clicks")],
)
def load_graph(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None or n_clicks == 0:
        return dash.no_update
    return html.Div(
        [
            html.Div(id="sigma-container", style={"width": "100%", "height": "500px", "border": "1px solid #ccc"}),
            html.Script(init_sigma_script),
            html.Script("initSigmaGraph();"),
        ]
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Can anyone please tell me how I can get the sigma graph to be rendered in the html.Div? Every help is as always very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`html.Script` can't be used for executing Javascript code:

```
html.Script

A Script component. Script is a wrapper for the <script> HTML5 element.

CAUTION: <script> is included for completeness, but you cannot execute JavaScript 
code by providing it to a <script> element. Use a clientside callback for this purpose instead.
```

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/script

As the documentation recommends here we can use a client side callback:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc                                                                                                                                                                      
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
app = Dash(__name__, assets_folder='assets', external_scripts=["https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sigma.js/1.2.0/sigma.min.js"])                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
app.layout = html.Div(                                                                                                                                                                                
    [                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        html.Div(id="dummy-output"),                                                                                                                                                                  
        html.Div(id="sigma-container", style={"width": "100%", "height": "500px", "border": "1px solid #ccc"}),                                                                                       
        html.Button(id="load-graph-button", children="Load Graph"),                                                                                                                                   
    ]                                                                                                                                                                                                 
)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
app.clientside_callback(                                                                                                                                                                              
    """                                                                                                                                                                                               
    function(nClicks) {                                                                                                                                                                               
        var s = new sigma(                                                                                                                                                                            
          {                                                                                                                                                                                           
            renderer: {                                                                                                                                                                               
              container: 'sigma-container',                                                                                                                                                           
              type: 'canvas'                                                                                                                                                                          
            },                                                                                                                                                                                        
            settings: {                                                                                                                                                                               
             minEdgeSize: 0.1,                                                                                                                                                                        
             maxEdgeSize: 2,                                                                                                                                                                          
             minNodeSize: 1,                                                                                                                                                                          
             maxNodeSize: 8,                                                                                                                                                                          
            }                                                                                                                                                                                         
          }                                                                                                                                                                                           
        );                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        // Create a graph object                                                                                                                                                                      
        var graph = {                                                                                                                                                                                 
          nodes: [                                                                                                                                                                                    
            { id: "n0", label: "A node", x: 0, y: 0, size: 3, color: '#008cc2' },                                                                                                                     
            { id: "n1", label: "Another node", x: 3, y: 1, size: 2, color: '#008cc2' },                                                                                                               
            { id: "n2", label: "And a last one", x: 1, y: 3, size: 1, color: '#E57821' }                                                                                                              
          ],                                                                                                                                                                                          
          edges: [                                                                                                                                                                                    
            { id: "e0", source: "n0", target: "n1", color: '#282c34', type:'line', size:0.5 },                                                                                                        
            { id: "e1", source: "n1", target: "n2", color: '#282c34', type:'curve', size:1},                                                                                                          
            { id: "e2", source: "n2", target: "n0", color: '#FF0000', type:'line', size:2}                                                                                                            
          ]                                                                                                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        // Load the graph in sigma                                                                                                                                                                    
        s.graph.read(graph);         

        // Add interactivity
        s.bind('clickNode', function(e) {
            alert('Node clicked: ' + e.data.node.label);
        });                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        // Ask sigma to draw it                                                                                                                                                                       
        s.refresh();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    """,                                                                                                                                                                                              
    Output("dummy-output", "children"),                                                                                                                                                               
    Input("load-graph-button", "n_clicks"),                                                                                                                                                           
    prevent_initial_call=True                                                                                                                                                                         
)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                                            
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

For the Javascript code I used this example here https://www.bsimard.com/2018/04/25/graph-viz-with-sigmajs.html and adjusted it slightly.